# Use of undeclared crate or module with workspaces

Tags: rust

I have the following structure:

```
-- project/
|
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- Cargo.lock
|-- src/ 
  |
  |-- main.rs
|-- crate1/
  |-- lib.rs
  |-- Cargo.toml
|-- tests
  |-- Cargo.toml
  |-- test.rs
```

and this are the content of the Cargo.toml

```ini
# Cargo.toml
...

[workspace]
members = [
  "crate1",

  "tests"
]

...
```

```ini
# crate1/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "crate1"

...

[lib]
path = "lib.rs"

...
```

here I'm using another lib for my tests, I don't think the problem is here, because I already used this way to do my tests several times, and it worked perfectly, but for some reason, now this is happening to me, I don't know if everything is a typo error of my self or not, but I already checked it a lot of times

```ini
# tests/Cargo.tom
[package]
name = "tests"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
publish = false

[dev-dependencies]
crate1 = { path = "../crate1" }

[[test]]
name = "crate1_test"
path = "crate1_test.rs"

[[test]]
name = "other_crate1_test"
path = "other_crate1_test.rs"
```

this is how one of the tests looks like

```rs
// tests/crate1_test.rs
use crate1::random_func;

[test]
fn random_func_test() {
    assert!(random_func());
}
```

And for some reason cargo don't recognize the "crate1" crate and throws me this error each time I import the crate:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `crate1`
 --> tests/crate1_test.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate1::random_func;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `crate1`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `project-manager` due to previous error
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact message for the error you're getting

Comment: there's the full error

Comment: With your setup I primarily get `[test]`: `expected item, found \`[\``. But if I replace `[test]` with `#[test]` your exact code works on my machine.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, your setup works for me. Did you try `cargo clean`? I think there is something missing here, because I can't see a mistake in the code you show.

Comment: First, sorry for my error, it actually is `#[test]` I just didn't notice i didn't wrote it in the question, and is the same doing `cargo clean` let me see if is something else

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was that I didn't make the `crate1` as a dependency of the main project, this is how my root `Cargo.toml` looks now:

```ini
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[workspace]
members = [
  "crate1",

  "tests"
]

[dependencies]
crate1 = { path = "crate1" }
reqwest = "0.11.13"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

and now I can build my tests correctly

Comment: That shouldn't have been necessary, it worked without that on my machine.

Answer (score -3):

In src/main.rs you have to add `mod crate1;` and potentially `mod tests;`

Comment: Why that? This doesn't make much sense to me